# SQL Server linked server to Interbase

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, interbase

I have created a linked server to an Interbase database with the OLE DB Provider from `IBProvider.com`. This worked really well, but apparently this IBProvider was only a test version which has expired. Instead of buying the full version I was wondering whether there is another way of fetching the data from that database or creating the linked server.

I know there is the `OPENDATASOURCE()` function allowing me to connect and query a remote data source.

But to use this function I need to enable DATA ACCESS on the server and I'm not sure what possible disadvantages this could have.

I could also use DTS and copy the tables to my SQL Server but I don't think this is best practise.

So, are there any other possibilites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found any solution to this so I bought the full version of this OLE DB Provider from [IBProvider.com](http://IBProvider.com)